# OpenVPN cannot connect over TCP

Tags: tcp, openvpn

The situation is: I have a Raspberry Pi 4B with Ubuntu 22.04LTS and run OpenVPN server on this which I installed from https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install with the link from https://computingforgeeks.com/easy-way-to-install-and-configure-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu/?expand_article=1. That worked, as long as I stick with UDP.

When I switch to TCP (here the server config)

```
local 192.168.0.60
port 1194
#proto udp
proto tcp-server
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "block-outside-dns"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
#explicit-exit-notify
```

the server starts normally, and indeed it is listening

```
root@raspberrypi:~# netstat -an  | grep 1194
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.60:1194       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     21194
```

but when I connect with the macOS OpenVPN connect app (in the same network, the address 192.168.0.60 is the router address of the PI and 10.8.0.1 the tun address of the Pi), I get these errors:

```
[Aug 2, 2023, 17:24:21] SetupClient: transmitting tun destroy request to /var/run/agent_ovpnconnect.sock
GET
unix:///var/run/agent_ovpnconnect.sock]/tun
-destroy: 200 OK
/sbin/route delete -net 10.8.0.0 -netmask
255.255.255.0 10.8.0.2
delete net 10.8.0.0: gateway 10.8.0.2
/sbin/route delete -net 10.8.0.0 -netmask
255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1
route: writing to routing socket: not in table delete net 10.8.0.0: gateway 10.8.0.1: not in table
/sbin/route delete -net 192.168.0.60 -netmask
255.255.255.255 192.168.0.254
delete net 192.168.0.60: gateway
192.168.0.254
/sbin/route delete -net 0.0.0.0 -netmask
128.0.0.0 10.8.0.1
delete net 0.0.0.0: gateway 10.8.0.1
/sbin/route delete -net 128.0.0.0 -netmask
128.0.0.0 10.8.0.1
delete net 128.0.0.0: gateway 10.8.0.1
/sbin/ifconfig utun3 down
MacDNSAction: FLAGS=ESF
[Aug 2, 2023, 17:24:21] MacLifeCycle
NET_IFACE en0
```

I first disabled the firewall `ufw disable` on the Pi to exclude firewall blocking any transfer.
The client looks like:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp-client
#proto udp

#remote raspberrypi.local 1194
remote 192.168.0.60 1194 tcp 
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
verb 3
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
# push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.60"
# push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

<ca>
CA
</ca>
<cert>
CERT
</cert>
<key>
KEY
</key>
<tls-crypt>
CRYPT
</tls-crypt>
```

UPDATE: This is when I connected from a Ubuntu OpenVPN client (NOT the Pi, from terminal `sudo openvpn ~/.config/openvpn/raspberrypi-tcp.ovpn`) using the same .ovpn as from the macOS client.

```
2023-08-02 18:44:52 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-08-02 18:44:52 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2023-08-02 18:44:52 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-08-02 18:44:52 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2023-08-02 18:44:52 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]192.168.0.60:1194
2023-08-02 18:44:52 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
2023-08-02 18:44:52 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]192.168.0.60:1194 [nonblock]
2023-08-02 18:44:52 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]192.168.0.60:1194 failed: Connection refused
2023-08-02 18:44:52 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),init_instance] received, process restarting
2023-08-02 18:44:52 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

I use the Pi as DNS server as it is running Pihole as well and that works normallt with UDP.

When I just change `proto tcp-client` to `proto udp` on the client side and  `proto tcp-server` to `proto udp` on the server (pi) side, everything works normally.
I tried just `proto tcp` on both sides as well.

What is going wrong ?

Comment: It says "Connection refused".  Are you sure that you opened port 1194/tcp on the server?